# $this jQuery chaining with .on click function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some html, five answer choices with the correct one for reference at the bottom. I've been trying to learn jQuery and came up with this code myself, and what I want to do is that if the user clicks on a answer choice that is equal to the value of the correct answer choice, $this or what the user clicked should turn green, and if the user clicks anything else it should turn red and remove all the other classes.

Here's what I have so far:
**HTML**

```
<div class="answer-choice" id="one">answer choice 1</div>

<div class="answer-choice" id="two">answer choice 2</div>

<div class="answer-choice" id="three">answer choice 3</div>

<div class="answer-choice" id="four">answer choice 4</div>

<div class="answer-choice" id="five">answer choice 5</div>

<hr>
<div class="correct-choice">answer choice 5</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".answer-choice").on("click", function(event) {
  var $this = $(this);

  if $this === (".correct-choice").text {
    $this.css({
      backgroundColor: '#000'
    });
  }
  else {
    $this.css({
      backgroundColor: '#f00'
    });
  }
});
```

Would appreciate any pointers and help.
Here's a link to my codepen where I did this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WKLEPV

Comment: `if $this ===` That's invalid syntax...

Comment: This line:     if $this === ("correct-choice").text {
contains several errors.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I looked it up and https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp says that === and == are both used as comparison operators :\

Comment: You need paranteses in an if sentence

Comment: Tell us what that sentence should mean (in plain English)

Comment: If the user clicks on a div with the class of .answer-choice, it should turn RED unless it matches the value of .correct-choice, then it should turn green

Comment: @Mazing: *«=== and == are both used as comparison operators»* is true... But there still is a difference between the two, where not just the value but also the type has to match. And on that line, you are comparing a jQuery object with the text of another. So type AND value just can't match.

Comment: I see that now, I understand. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is syntactically wrong in the following line:

```
if $this === (".correct-choice").text {
```

If the answer is correct then reset the color to the default color for all the answers except the current answer.

Try the following way:

```js
$(".answer-choice").on("click",
function(event) {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.text() === $(".correct-choice").text()) {
    $this.css({
        backgroundColor: '#0f0'
    });

    $(".answer-choice").not(this).each(function(){
        $(this).css({
          backgroundColor: '#fff'
      });
    });
  }
  else {
    $this.css({
        backgroundColor: '#f00'
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="answer-choice" id="one">answer choice 1</div>

<div class="answer-choice" id="two">answer choice 2</div>

<div class="answer-choice" id="three">answer choice 3</div>

<div class="answer-choice" id="four">answer choice 4</div>

<div class="answer-choice" id="five">answer choice 5</div>

<hr>
<div class="correct-choice">answer choice 5</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your have syntax errors with your Javascript code. You need parentheses in your `if` statement.

```
if $this === ("correct-choice").text
```

should be

```
if ($this.hasClass("correct-choice"))
```

You also need to give the correct answer a class of `answer-choice` so the click event listener will also work on it. You should use jQuery's `.hasClass` method to determine if the answer choice clicked on has a class of `correct-choice` in which case it is the correct answer.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="answer-choice" id="one">answer choice 1</div>

<div class="answer-choice" id="two">answer choice 2</div>

<div class="answer-choice" id="three">answer choice 3</div>

<div class="answer-choice" id="four">answer choice 4</div>

<div class="answer-choice correct-choice" id="five">answer choice 5</div>

<script>
$(".answer-choice").on("click",
    function(event) {


        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.hasClass("correct-choice")) {
            $this.css({
                backgroundColor: '#33ff33'
            });
            $('.answer-choice').not($this).each(function(){
                $(this).css("backgroundColor", "white");
            });

        }
        else {

            $this.css({
                backgroundColor: '#f00'
            });
            $('.correct-choice').css("backgroundColor", "white");
        }



    });
</script>
```

Comment: This does not work by the way, all the choices turn red, none turn green :\

Comment: @mazing The choice after the `hr` is the one with the class `correct-choice`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now I think I got it, try this:

```
if ($this.text() === $(".correct-choice").text())
```

That should work